# Only a wordpress group of user can access to a folder using .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, usergroups

I don't know a lot about `.htaccess`.
I have a web with Wordpress and I made a part private only for subscribers. I have installed a couple of Wordpress plugins to control the access to that page. The problem is that the "private" page links to a folder where I have a lot of `.html` pages. That is the folder I want to protect. I have used the `http_refered` in the `.htaccess` but I know it is very easy to hack it.

Is there any way to write in the `.htaccess` file a command that check the Wordpress user file and see if the user belongs to the "suscriber" group?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to protect the private page with password (this is common feature in Wordpress) and do not mess with the `.htaccess` file.

Anyhow, the is no way to tell the Apache (because the `.htaccess` is applied from it) that this or that user is registered or approved user. This can be done on different level - PHP and/or Wordpress logic.

Comment: My problem is that the folder I want to protect is not wordpress. The matter is that I have a lot of books converted in flash/html5 and the main link to read them is a basic .html. So that's my problem... With Wordpress I don't see the way to manage those .html and the only way I see is the htaccess.